# Has Unix Parameter Name SystemAudioVolume Been Changed to SystemAudioVolume DB in El Capitan?

Tags: terminal, audio, unix, startup

I am trying to change the startup sound. When I checked the setting using:

```
sudo nvram -p
```

it returns a setting for SystemAudioVolume DB  %ee

I entered:

```
    sudo nvram SystemAudioVolume=%00
```

When I check again using sudo nvram -p

both names show up in the list:

SystemAudioVolume DB .... %ee

SystemAudioVolume .... %00 (it took my setting but doesn't kill sound)

Should I be trying to set SystemAudioVolume DB instead?

If yes, is this the right way?

```
sudo nvram SystemAudioVolumeDB=%aa
```

(No space before DB.) Does anyone know the proper range for this?
My computer is old but I don't want to break it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, the `sudo nvram SystemAudioVolume=%00` (or the same command with different values at end) never allowed users to actually **change** the startup chime sound. In earlier versions of Mac OS X it did allow users to change the volume, and therefore they could *mute* the startup chime, but this did not change the sound.

The closest thing to changing the sound is a hack that allowed users to mute the startup chime and then add another sound that occurred upon logging in to your user account - but of course this is not a startup sound, just a sound that plays when you log into your user account.

As for whether `SystemAudioVolume` has been replaced with `SystemAudioVolumeDB`, the answer is no. In fact, as you have seen from running `sudo nvram -p`, these two parameters have totally different values.

**Summary**

- No, the Unix parameter `SystemAudioVolume` has not been replaced by `SystemAudioVolume DB` in El Capitan
- The Unix parameter `SystemAudioVolume` has never been used to *change* the startup chime sound - only to change the volume level
- The startup chime sound cannot be changed

**Further reading**

These related questions may interest you:

- [Disable OS X startup sound](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/168092/disable-os-x-startup-sound)
- [How can I silence the startup chime on El Capitan?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/246383/how-can-i-silence-the-startup-chime-on-el-capitan)

Comment: So sorry, I meant I want to change the startup sound volume, not the sound itself.

You said the two parameters have totally different values —

Comment: You said the two parameters have totally different values — 

SystemAudioVolume only appeared in the list after I set it. I later reset the default parameters with:

    sudo nvram -d SystemAudioVolume 

After doing this, I checked it again and the term SystemAudioVolume does not even appear in the list, only SystemAudioVolume DB shows up. This lead me to suppose it had been changed.

I don't want to silence the sound, just make it soft.